# Pictures that switch each time you open a program

Tags: javascript, hta

I need some help, I have a launcher that I made in HTA (Hyper Text Aplication).I have a logo that says Launcher in red, but I also have another Logo that says Launcher in Blue, is it possible to use JavaScript or some programming language to make the pictures swap each time you open the program?

Regards

Petzl11

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Have an array of Logo images, and pick a random one to display from that array on every startup.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I could make one?

Comment: But this displayes 3 images, i need it to display one at a time :/
But thanks for your help :D

Comment: Look at any of the related questions to the right, but that should get you started with loading some random images. :)

Comment: I used this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428154/javascript-random-image-selected-on-refresh?rq=1 , but I get this error:
Error: Unable to set property 'src' of undefined or null reference, can you help me?

Comment: Post another question; I assume you mean [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16428237/2970947).